# If I use Fetch API response is proper but if i use api-utility I got CORS error

Tags: angular, fetch

Working code:
If I use Fetch API response comes but if I use api-utility got CORS error.

```
   fetch('https://upxselling.com/UpXsell/getService?action=getAllTemplate', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        emailId: 'n@upx.com'
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json ))
```

You can check above code in browser console. it returns JSON response.

My query is when I call this post by api-utility architecture it gives me error 
like :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://api.upxselling.com/UpXsell/getService?action=getAllTemplate'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>
> api-utility.service.ts:47 Backend returned code 0, body was: Response
>   with status: 0  for URL: null frame.component.ts:44

```
this.service.getTemplates().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.templates = data;
}, (err: any) => {
  console.log("error");
  this.spinner.hide();
}, () => {
  console.log("Finally");
  this.spinner.hide();
})
```

## Template.service.ts

```
  getTemplates(): Observable<Template[]> {
    return this.api.post('getService?action=getAllTemplate');
  }
```

## api-utility-service.ts

```
export class ApiUtilityService {
  constructor(
    private http: Http, private toaster: ToastrService, private jwtService: JwtService
  ) { }


  /**
   * To set headers in requst.
   */
  private setHeaders(): Headers {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
    };


    return new Headers(headersConfig);
    // return new Headers();
  }


  post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${environment.apiUrl}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      { headers: this.setHeaders() }
    ).
      pipe(map((resp: Response) => resp.json()), catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }
```

Comment: why do you set this in the second part?    'access-control-allow-origin': '*'.  the error states.   you are not allowed to set in pre-flight (meaning complex requests).  try without.

Comment: I tried by removing 'access-control-allow-origin': '*' still facing the same issue.

Comment: I think you need to set a policy on the server. please check the cors middleware on node / express

Comment: If cors issue then why fetch api is working and not the http?